# php not executed properly

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

i have the following code html+php in a .php and the PHP its not executed properly...

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option value="Select"><?php echo "Select";?></option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

this is a simple code that i tried to run, but the 'Select' doesn't appeared.

The server accept PHP because i have other scripts that run perfectly.

EDIT: i used file_get_contents to get the .php file where this code was... and this is probably the root of the problem.

EDIT 2: I was able to execute the PHP code using this

```
ob_start();
include("form.php");
$htmlPage = ob_get_clean();
```

where the select is inside form.php

Thank you all

Comment: This code works, check your server configuration. What is the output, an error, the php code?

Comment: It should be working. How does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: The code (Like said befor) is working, but maybe your server doesn't support php / file extenstion didn't renamed to .php

Comment: What's the point of `<option value="Select"><?php echo "Select";?></option>`? Wouldn't plain HTML be easier?

Comment: If "select" doesn't appear, what does appear?

Comment: @j08691 I think he gave an example, he doesn't really want to use this pirticular code, maybe he wanna add something more complicated in the future.

Comment: @BadWolf, The post says PHP runs perfectly in other scripts.

Comment: @Yotam - then he should post representative code.

Comment: I have a feeling instead of `Select` he wants `$Select` but who knows... also, make sure the page is called whatever.php and not whatever.html

Comment: in the future i want to use PHP $_SESSION to define the previously selected value.

When a execute the above code a dont get nothing... its like the code is this <option value="Select"></option>

Comment: @cantsay, the page is called whatever.php

Comment: @BAndrade Do you got related codes to this code? like css or javascript?

Comment: Are you running this code locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the extra information that you are using `file_get_contents()`, the solution is to understand the difference between *reading* a file and *evaluating* it; from the manual:

- [`file_get_contents` — Reads entire file into a string](http://php.net/file_get_contents)
- [The `include` statement includes and evaluates the specified file.](http://php.net/include)

Since code outside of any `<?php ... ?>` block is processed as direct output, `include 'example.html';` is equivalent to `echo file_get_contents('example.html');` if `example.html` is a file with no PHP code in. However, `file_get_contents` doesn't know or care what is in the file - it just puts the contents into a string variable. In contrast, `include` (and the variants `include_once`, `require`, and `require_once`) is specifically *evaluating* the file rather than just *reading* it, so PHP code is executed and everything else is output to the browser (note: it is *not* put into a variable).

Since `include` outputs directly, you should never need to say `echo include...`; it is also a *statement*, not a *function*, so does not need brackets around the argument.

Comment: i was able to execute the code using this instead of file_get_contents...

ob_start();
include("form.php");
$htmlPage = ob_get_clean();

the code in the question is inside form.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved your file with a `.php` extension and not a `.html` extension.

Comment: he said he does in comments above.

Comment: @Vector i saved the file as .php file...

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have posted. Post the rest of your code. Check you have uploaded the new file, refresh, clear cache etc etc. If still the problem persists post a link here to the site.

Comment: @Vector first, it was a .html form that is invoked inside a .php file, like this $htmlPage=file_get_contents($_SESSION["static"]."form.html",false);

and recently, as i tried to use PHP code inside, i renamed the file to .php and change the above call to it. 

the .php file looks like...

<html>
<body>
<form>
(... the code i put on the post above ...)
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @BAndrade This is vital info that should be in your question. `file_get_contents()` will not execute PHP code in the file, only get the literal contents of that file.

Comment: @IMSoP thank you a lot... i will add this info to question

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've decided to run it my self (using **Wamp** server) and I achive working result.
Here is an [image](http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/2305/08xu.png) of your code in my php localhost server.

**Possible Issues**

*Issue number 1:* Well, mustly alike your server doesn't support PHP, but since you said he support other script I would advice you to recheck server setting.

*Issue number 2:* You've added some kind of related codes (Like CSS or JavaScript, even due you said you didn't, you might have a slight mastaik) that blocks you existed code. (i.e **CSS** code `option:first-child{ display: none; };`)

If none of my tips/possible issues works I suggest you reinstall your server (incase it webhost server, pass to another one)

Comment: i have some <script></script> on the file two, but not interacting with that area in specific. but, can it be the origin of the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this more simple code first..

Just make a file "index.php"
& put this one line

```
<?php echo "Hello";?>
```

now save & execute it
If this line will print "Hello" ....then try your code.

Thanks